# How to determine the largest number of disconnected arcs in a graph?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

Given a directed graph $G=(V,E)$, I'm wondering if there's a way to determine the largest size of a set of edges that are disconnected pairwise. There is a similar problem for vertices (Maximum Independent Set).  However, I'm unable to think of the corresponding problem for edges.

When I say "two disconnected edges" I mean the following:

- $(u,v)$ to $(u,w)$ are "disconnected" since the tail of one does not equal the tip of the other.
- $(u,v)$ to $(w,v)$ are "disconnected" since the tail of one does not equal the tip of the other.
- $(u,v)$ to $(v,w)$ are "connected" since the tail of one *does* equal the tip of the other.

What is the name of this type of problem?

Comment: This is similar to the maximum matching problem, although somewhat different because you allow edges with the same starting or ending point

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be reduced to the *maximum independent set problem*. Let $G = (V,E)$ be the input instance of the problem. Then, create a new graph $G'$ such that each vertex in $G'$ corresponds to an edge in $G$. Two vertices in $G'$ have an edge between them if and only if the corresponding edges are connected in $G$. The following claim follows easily.

*Claim*: There exists a set of $k$ pairwise-disconnected edges in $G$ if and only if $G'$ has an independent set of size $k$.